# python syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

when I try to run this code :

```
def table():
    nb = 7
    i = 0
    while i < 20 :
        if ((i+1)*nb)%3 == 0 :
            print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb'*')
        else :
            print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb)

    i += 1
```

I get an syntax error for this part (the last ')

```
        print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb'*')
```

And I really don't understant why, is there any issue ?

Comment: what do you expect `nb'*'` to mean exactly?

Comment: That might be the python 4 syntax for non-byte string `nb'*'` :P

Answer (score 10):

I suspect you're trying to do:

```
print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb, '*')
                                     ^
```

Note the comma before the final argument.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma. Try this:

```
print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb , '*')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma, and also your indentation was all wrong:

```
def table():
    nb = 7
    i = 0
    while i<20 :
        if ((i+1)*nb)%3==0 :
            print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb, '*')
        else :
            print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb)

        i +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is here : `print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb'*')`

in the `(i+1)*nb'*'` .......the nb and ' are not seperated.

```
print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb, '*')
```

should be right

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `nb'*'`, which is equivalent to 7'*'.  There is no int/str juxtaposition operator, I guess you want:

```
print(i+1 , "*" , nb , "=" , (i+1)*nb*'*')
```

but you really aren't clear in this programme.  I would probably use something like:

```
def table(multiplier=7, maximum=20):
    for i in range(1, maximum+1):
        answer = i * multiplier
        if (answer) % 3 == 0:
            print("%d * %d = %s" % (i, multiplier, '*' * answer))
        else :
            print("%d * %d = %d" % (i, multiplier, answer))
```

as it's got clear variable names, allows you to pass in specific multipliers and uses a more pythonic loop.